# How come store.add() method does not perform mapping?

Tags: extjs, extjs4, extjs5

I have a nested json data, namely:

```
{
name: 'alex',
 tel: {
    personal: '347xxxx',
    work: '331xxxx'
 }
}
```

Then the following model:

```
Ext.define("Employer", {
    extend: 'Ext.data.Model',
    idProperty: 'personalTel',
    fields: [...
            {name: 'personalTel', mapping: 'tel.personal'}
```

Finally the following store:

```
Ext.create('Ext.data.Store',{ 
        model: 'Employer',
        proxy: {
            type: 'memory',
            reader: {
                type: 'json',
                root: 'root'
            }
        },
        data: myInitialData //an array containing json objects
```

As long as the data is contained in myInitialData the personalTel field is correctly set.
However, adding a new record to the store does not trigger the mapping and so I find myself with strange personalTel property, that is automatic IDs extjs puts!

Answer (score 1):

ExtJS allows you to load multiple models via nesting when using a reader. It does not allow those models to be created when instantiating the model directly, which is what adding the object to the store does.

The idea is that each model is treated separately with its own store. Want to add a customer with a telephone number? Create the telephone number first, put it in its store, then create the customer with a reference to the telephone number.

This approach is a bit clumsy, though, and only works with models that really are separate entities.

An alternative approach would be to use a custom type, or simply to use the 'auto' type (which treats the data as a blob that you can do what you want with). Both approaches have their drawbacks.